Azure Sql server metrics - cpu_percentage vs sql_instance_cpu_percent
Im working on developing autoscaling for Azure Hyperscale Gen5 sql dbs.
For that, I need to monitor the cpu usage, to know when to scale its vcores up or down .
There are 2 sql cpu metrics - "cpu_percentage" and "sql_instance_cpu_percent" .
From what i read, sql_instance_cpu_percent shows the cpu usage of the server as a whole including system services etc, and cpu_percentage is per a specific process.
Meaning, the sql_instance_cpu_percent would always be HIGHER than cpu_percentage.
However, whe running a load test on a db (lots of reads,write,deletions), Im seeing the cpu_percentage go way up above sql_cpu_instance_percent.
Why could that be ? is cpu_percentage maybe a better metrics to consider when planning scaling operations ?

I base all my up/down scaling on this query:
DECLARE @StartDate date = DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()) -- 14 Days

SELECT
    @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName
    ,database_name AS DatabaseName
    ,sysso.edition
    ,sysso.service_objective
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 dtu_limit FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs3 WHERE rs3.database_name = rs1.database_name ORDER BY rs3.start_time DESC)  AS DTU
    /*,(SELECT TOP 1 storage_in_megabytes FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs2 WHERE rs2.database_name = rs1.database_name ORDER BY rs2.start_time DESC)  AS StorageMB */
    /*,(SELECT TOP 1 allocated_storage_in_megabytes FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs4 WHERE rs4.database_name = rs1.database_name ORDER BY rs4.start_time DESC)  AS Allocated_StorageMB*/ 
    ,avcon.AVG_Connections_per_Hour
    ,CAST(MAX(storage_in_megabytes) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) StorageGB
    ,CAST(MAX(allocated_storage_in_megabytes) / 1024 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) Allocated_StorageGB
    ,MIN(end_time) AS StartTime
    ,MAX(end_time) AS EndTime
    ,CAST(AVG(avg_cpu_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_CPU
    ,MAX(avg_cpu_percent) AS Max_CPU
    ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_cpu_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [CPU Fit %]
    ,CAST(AVG(avg_data_io_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_IO
    ,MAX(avg_data_io_percent) AS Max_IO
    ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_data_io_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Data IO Fit %]
    ,CAST(AVG(avg_log_write_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS Avg_LogWrite
    ,MAX(avg_log_write_percent) AS Max_LogWrite
    ,(COUNT(database_name) - SUM(CASE WHEN avg_log_write_percent >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(database_name) * 100 AS [Log Write Fit %]
    ,CAST(AVG(max_session_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS 'Average % of sessions'
    ,MAX(max_session_percent) AS 'Maximum % of sessions'
    ,CAST(AVG(max_worker_percent) AS decimal(4,2)) AS 'Average % of workers'
    ,MAX(max_worker_percent) AS 'Maximum % of workers'
  
  
FROM sys.resource_stats AS rs1
inner join sys.databases dbs on rs1.database_name = dbs.name
INNER JOIN sys.database_service_objectives sysso on sysso.database_id = dbs.database_id
inner join 

(SELECT t.name
    ,round(avg(CAST(t.Count_Connections AS FLOAT)), 2) AS AVG_Connections_per_Hour
FROM (
    SELECT name
        --,database_name
        --,success_count
        --,start_time
        ,CONVERT(DATE, start_time) AS Dating
        ,DATEPART(HOUR, start_time) AS Houring
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN name = database_name
                    THEN success_count
                ELSE 0
                END) AS Count_Connections
    FROM sys.database_connection_stats
    CROSS JOIN sys.databases
    WHERE start_time > @StartDate
        AND database_id != 1
    GROUP BY name
        ,CONVERT(DATE, start_time)
        ,DATEPART(HOUR, start_time)
    ) AS t
GROUP BY t.name) avcon on avcon.name = rs1.database_name


WHERE start_time > @StartDate
AND rs1.start_time > @StartDate 
GROUP BY database_name, sysso.edition, sysso.service_objective,avcon.AVG_Connections_per_Hour
ORDER BY database_name , sysso.edition, sysso.service_objective

Now: why are you trying to scale Hyperscale?
I't called Hyperscale... because it scales. So why are you scaling it? I mostly use this query for DTU vCores.
UPDATE: I want to add a few words for the posterity.
If you are reading this post it's probably because you are trying to minimize the cost of your Azure SQL Databases.
I've banged my head against this problem multiple times. I've contacted the Azure support multiple times. I've meet with folks and chatted about this multiple times. And there is only one solution:

The only way to archive auto-scaling is serverless

Go ahead and try to put in place the notorious solution, then a few things will happen:

When the auto-scale based on the 80% of CPU usage of the last 5 minutes will chick in your database might take 5, 10, 20, 50 minutes to scale. It will mostly be useless
The scale cannot take place till all queries have completed  and new queries are waiting in the queue. As result you application is now down
For the two reason previously mentioned, if you put this "hard way" scale in place every 5 minutes you will mostly incur in data corruption
I haven't investigate yet what happens but from my experience the backup of vCores (PITR) arrives to increase 3-4 times the actual size of the storage. As result, if you investigate the Azure SQL Database Sub Meter Category PITR you will find out that most of the cost of your database is now the backup, which is now more expensive than the database itself.
You cannot base your scaling only on the cpu_percetnage, you have to count in also Log I/O and Data I/O.

SOLUTION:
The data that the query picks up are based on the last 14 days.
I'm trying to use the query that I posted here to create an auto-scale that chicks bi-weekly (or weekly).
This way you can decide if you want to base your scaling on the AVG or the MAX usage of CPU, Log I/O, Data I/O.
Still manual for now. Will be automated one day. Maybe.

Wow thats very complex.
Hyperscale Gen5 which we use, allows fast scaling but doesn't actually scale. Serverless does, but we dont use it here.
So Im developing a tool that monitors CPU % metrics and scales up/down based on the need.
Thanks for sharing your query but I think its an overkill for me.
I've reached out to Azure and they said the right metric for me is cpu_percetnage.
Thanks anyway.

I've been trying to create a tool for auto scaling too. And out there there are hundreds of people that tried too. You have probably already read this: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/how-to-auto-scale-azure-sql-databases/ba-p/2235441 and the reply is no, you cannot put this in place. For reasons that if you want I can explain you in a chat. Bottom line: you can scale weekly or bi-weekly but not based on resource demand every 5 minutes.

Would love to have a chat to understand the reason why this can't be done.
I've ran this on a test db with some load testing and it did seem to do the trick.
Where can we chat about this ?

I put an update

Is it possible that your takebacks from trying the autoscale based on metrics, applies mostly to rapidly changing databases? In my case, the databases are mostly on low CPU, and i can give a general estimation that 5% of a given time there's actually spikes that require scale-up.
Also, the API call I use awaits for the result of the scale up + has a holdoff timer of 2 minutes, So I dont think duplicate scleup events should happen.
From my tests of having a db with 2 vcores, then loading it so it jumps to 100%, it worked well.. I will have a look at that PITR backup you've mentioned.
